# Drupal6 - Mobile version issue

Tags: mobile, drupal-6

Hi
Suppose I have menu A, menu B...Menu F in desktop version, I want to display only menu A and menu B in mobile version. The quickly way is using CSS with display:none, but is there any Drupal's API that I can use for this situation?

On the other hand, I want to redirect to http://xxx/product instead of http://xxx/index.php for home page in mobile version, any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [mobile tools module](https://drupal.org/project/mobile_tools) to detect the device and switch themes accordingly. Each theme could then have a different menu configured to display.